# How can I collect errors that occur while executing statements using DBI?

Tags: perl, dbi

When the query fails, I need to add an error message to an array.

This is my executing line:

```
 $txnQuery[$t] = $sth_Data->execute(@argsIn);
```

I'm trying something like this:

```
$txnQuery[$t] = $sth_Data->execute(@argsIn) or die push(@Error,"SQL Error");
```

Comment: You're trying that, and... what's happening? The script is dying?

Comment: print this error: 1 at E:\StatementJSON.pl line 395. I think the or die only print in the page, it cant do any else action.

Comment: The `1` you're seeing is probably the number of elements in `@Error`, which is what `push` returns. I don't understand what the question is, though. If you don't want the script to exit, don't call `die`.

Comment: Yeah is correct, but the instruction 'or die' cannot do another action, only can print I think, then how I can evaluate the SQL statement to realize this action?, for example with an if

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`DBI` module](http://metacpan.org/module/DBI) provides the `PrintError`, `RaiseError`, and `HandleError` options to tune how you want error handling to work. The first two are just flags, but [`HandleError`](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI#HandleError) may be set to a subroutine reference that will allow you to write exactly what you want to happen in the event of an error

For instance, you can create something like the behaviour of `RaiseError` by writing

```
$dbh->{HandleError} = sub {
    my ($msg, $dbh, $ret) = @_;
    die $msg;
};
```

or you could accumulate a list of errors that occur, as you describe, by just pushing onto an array. Something like this, perhaps

```
my @errors;

$dbh->{HandleError} = sub {
    my ($msg, $dbh, $ret) = @_;
    push @errors, $msg;
};
```

If you also want a message printed to the console then you can `warn $msg` within your error handler, or you can simply leave `PrintError` set

You may want to add a timestamp to each item that you push onto the array, and it's possible to do something more elaborate using the database handle parameter `$dbh`, and `$ret`, which is the return value of the failing `DBI` method

Comment: Thank you sir, thats works, I was reading about the other DBI error management and the sentence 'eval' works too.

Comment: @BernadoBorunda: `eval` is for preventing a fatal error from terminating your program. So in this case you would have to set `RaiseError` to make errors fatal and then use `eval` to prevent your program from dying, which seems a little nonsensical. Also, you have to use `eval` on *every* database operation, whereas assigning a subroutine to `HandleError` needs to be done only once